# How to insert into relational tables?

Tags: python, mysql

I've got a relational database and I'm trying to learn how to insert rows. Here's what I've got:

```
artist {id, name}
genre  {id, name}
album  {id, name, artist_id, genre_id}
track  {id, album_id, track_name}
```

My biggest issue is that I'd like `artist` to be unique, so that there cannot be artists with identical names, but every query I've tried inserts duplicates. I've tried changing the table to unique, but I've found it impossible to then add more than one track by a single artist. At this point I'm stuck; I've looked into ON DUPLICATE statements without success, and even attempted trying to detect duplicates in my script and running different inserts from there.

Thanks for any help you can offer.

Comment: can't there be possibilities that two artists have the same name?

Answer (score 0):

According to your database design it should work fine. I'm asssuming that all `ids` are `primary key` for their respective tables. Also give the constraint `UNIQUE` for artist name. And if you are using a script to create tables, make sure to commit after entry. Now u CANT insert a name that is already present. Also make foreign keys. This sample code works fine with sqlite in python3.

```
import sqlite3 as sql
a = sql.connect('test_db')
conn = a.cursor()

query = 'create table artists(id INTEGER primary key AUTOINCREMENT, artist_name varchar(30) unique)'
conn.execute(query)
query2 = 'create table albums(id INTEGER primary key AUTOINCREMENT, artist_id integer, foreign key(artist_id) references artists(id))'
conn.execute(query2)
query3 = 'create table tracks(id INTEGER primary key AUTOINCREMENT, album_name varchar(30), album_id integer, foreign key(album_id) references albums(id))'
conn.execute(query3)

conn.execute('insert into artists(artist_name) values("john")')
conn.execute('insert into artists(artist_name) values("Doe")')
conn.execute('insert into albums(artist_id) values(1)')
conn.execute('insert into albums(artist_id) values(2)')
conn.execute('insert into tracks(album_name, album_id) values("something",1)')
conn.execute('insert into tracks(album_name, album_id) values("someotherthing",2)')

a.commit()
```

Hope this helps :)

Comment: While this is helpful, this query `insert into albums(artist_id) values(1)` would require me to know the artist_id at runtime, correct? My goal was to generate the primary keys with each unique entry via autoincrement. Correct me if I'm wrong, but to do this wouldn't I first need to check if the artist already exists, and then use its primary key in the same query?

The whole point of this project is to monitor the music I listen to and then add the songs to this database once every day or so. Since I'm continually adding entries, is checking for duplicates before each entry unavoidable?

Answer (score 0):

Why rely on the structure of the database to prevent duplicates?
This is easily done when you are loading the data.
The following is using `sqlite3` and probably needs improvement:

Data file catalog.txt:

```
album 1,artist 1,rock,track 1
album 1,artist 1,rock,track 2
album 1,artist 1,rock,track 3
album 1,artist 1,rock,track 4
album 1,artist 1,rock,track 5
album 1,artist 1,rock,track 6
album 1,artist 1,rock,track 7
album 1,artist 1,rock,track 8
album 1,artist 1,rock,track 9
album 1,artist 1,rock,track 10
album 2,artist 1,rock,track 1
album 2,artist 1,rock,track 2
album 2,artist 1,rock,track 3
album 2,artist 1,rock,track 4
album 2,artist 1,rock,track 5
album 3,artist 2,regge,track 1
album 3,artist 2,regge,track 2
album 3,artist 2,regge,track 3
album 2,artist 3,rock,track 1
album 2,artist 3,rock,track 2
album 2,artist 3,rock,track 3
album 2,artist 3,rock,track 4
album 2,artist 3,rock,track 5
```

Code:
This does allow duplicate album names if the artist is different
It relies upon the `autoincrement` for the keys when inserting new records

```
import sqlite3
db_name = "catalog.db"
db = sqlite3.connect(db_name, isolation_level=None)
db.row_factory = sqlite3.Row
cursor = db.cursor()
result = cursor.execute("create table if not exists artist (artist_id integer primary key autoincrement,artist_name char(150))")
result = cursor.execute("create table if not exists genre (genre_id integer primary key autoincrement,genre_name char(150))")
result = cursor.execute("create table if not exists album (album_id integer primary key autoincrement,album_name char(150),artist_id int,genre_id int)")
result = cursor.execute("create table if not exists track (track_id integer primary key autoincrement,track_name char(150),album_id int)")

with open('catalog.txt','r') as f:
    data = f.readlines()

for i in data:
    track = i.split(',')
    alb = track[0].strip()
    art = track[1].strip()
    gen = track[2].strip()
    tra = track[3].strip()

    #Check for existing artist
    cursor.execute("select artist_id from artist where artist_name = ?",[art])
    data = cursor.fetchone()
    if data:
        art_id = data['artist_id']
    else: #Insert new record then record the new id
        db.execute("insert into artist(artist_name) values (?)",(art,))
        cursor.execute("select artist_id from artist where artist_name = ?",[art])
        data = cursor.fetchone()
        art_id = data['artist_id']
        print "Adding artist", art

    #Check for existing genre
    cursor.execute("select genre_id from genre where genre_name = ?",[gen])
    data = cursor.fetchone()
    if data:
        gen_id = data['genre_id']
    else: #Insert new record then record the new id
        db.execute("insert into genre(genre_name) values (?)",(gen,))
        cursor.execute("select genre_id from genre where genre_name = ?",[gen])
        data = cursor.fetchone()
        gen_id = data['genre_id']
        print "  Adding genre", gen

    #Check for existing album by given artist
    cursor.execute("select album_id from album where album_name = ? and artist_id = ?",[alb,art_id])
    data = cursor.fetchone()
    if data:
        alb_id = data['album_id']
    else: #Insert new record then record the new id
        db.execute("insert into album(album_name,artist_id,genre_id) values (?,?,?)",(alb,art_id,gen_id,))
        cursor.execute("select album_id from album where album_name = ? and artist_id = ?",[alb,art_id])
        data = cursor.fetchone()
        alb_id = int(data[0])
        print "    Adding album", alb

    #Check for track in given album
    cursor.execute("select track_id from track where album_id = ? and track_name = ?",[alb_id,tra])
    data = cursor.fetchone()
    if data:
        pass # duplicate"
    else:
        db.execute("insert into track(track_name,album_id) values (?,?)",(tra,alb_id,))
        print "      Adding", tra, art, alb
```

Answer (score -1):

how do you access your database? Are you using any kind of ORM?

In general you may not insert the artist again for every track.

So on inserting your album, you should lookup your table, if the artist already exists. If it exists, fetch it's id and reuse it when inserting tracks. If the artist doesn't exist yet, insert it and save the artist_id for iterating over the track list and inserting each track using the artist_id.